# Big O notation (The complexity) of the following code?

Tags: java

I just wondering what is the big o for the code below:

I am thinking O(n). What do you guys think? Thank you for your help!

```
for( w = Length ; w >= 0 ; w = w / 2 ){
   for( i = Length ; i >= 0 ; --i ){
      if(  randomNumber() == 4  )
         return
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you think it is?

Comment: Hint: You have nested loops and no particular bounds on how large the loop boundary can be, and no indication of how likely randomNumber is to be 4.

Comment: Depends on  `randomNumber()`: from `O(1)` if, say, the very 1st `randomNumber() == 4` up to `O(Length**2)` if `randomNumber()` is never equals to 4; so `O(Length)` is just *possible*

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for the `Big O` notation, which is the worst case time complexity, the answer is:

`O(n^x)` , where x is the denominator used in the outer-for loop.

Comment: So quadratic runtime? This is correct, but you can have a tighter bound if the variables are integers.

Comment: Actually, a upper bound of O(2^n) is also correct, as it is larger than the runtime in any case.

Answer (score 1):

This pretty much looks like a class assignment, so I do not answer it, but just give you some pointers (homework should not be done by copying the assignment to the web ;) ). Also the assignment is incomplete. I hope your teacher/lecturer did not give it like this.

The missing information is:

- Are you looking for worst case runtime or average case runtime? Big-O can be used for both. [originally I included best case runtime, but this is done with big omega, as Jerry pointed out in the comments]
- Another missing piece is the datatype of the variables. If they are doubles, it takes much longer until w = w/2 is 0 than with integers.

Worst-case runtime:

The inner loop has i = i-1, so it is executed length times. This gives you O(n) for the inner loop.

This already shows that your estimate is wrong. It has to be the number of executions of the outer loop TIMES the number of executions of the inner loop, so it must be more than linear (unless the outer loop has constant number of executions).

The outer loop has w = w/2, so, in terms of length, how long will this need to be 0? This gives you how often the outer loop is executed. And, by multiplication, the total number of executions.

Than there is this randomNumber(). As I said I am assuming worst-case analysis, the worst case is clearly that it is never 4 and thereby we can ignore this return.

Average-case runtime:

The analysis for the loops does not change. For the randomNumber(), we need to estimate how long it takes until the probability of NOT having 4 is sufficiently small. However, I do not have enough information about randomNumber() to do this.

Best-case runtime [should be big omega, not big o]:

In the best case, randomNumber() returns 4 on the first call. So the best case runtime is constant, O(1).

Comment: The best case is represented as Big Omega, not Big O